# Not able to get SlidesJS working

Tags: javascript, html, carousel

I'm testing [SlidesJS](http://slidesjs.com/#examples) for scrolling list elements, but I'm not quite getting it to work. According to the examples, it looks very simple.

This is the js I'm using:

```
$("#fp-slider-container .slides_container").slides();
```

and My markup looks like this:

```
<div class="blue-gradient" id="fp-slider-container">
  <div class="main-content-container">
    <div class="item-container">
      <ul class="slides_container">
        <li>
          <div class="fp-slider-content">
            <h1>Web design</h1>
            <div>Some text here</div>
            <div class="more"><a href="#" title="Web design">more</a> » </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="fp-slider-content">
            <h1>Photography</h1>
            <div>Some more text here</div>
            <div class="more"><a href="#" title="Photography">more</a> » </div>
          </div>
        </li>            
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have my [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/gK8Lc/).

Is my JSfiddle not working because I've added the SlidesJS into the javascript box? Or is it not working because I'm using `<ul><li>` ?

Expected result is a carousel of the list elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your js call needs to look like this:

`$("#fp-slider-container").slides();`

Comment: Of course I'm importing the JS file. Otherwise I would get a js error saying that `slides()` is an unknown function.

Comment: Sorry. I've just noticed that your js looks like this 
`$("#fp-slider-container .slides_container").slides();`, and should look like this:
`$("#fp-slider-container").slides();`. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Yes, I changed html and removed `item-container` and got it working :)